# Arduino Ethernet Shield delay

Tags: arduino

I am working on an arduino board with Ethernet Shield (v2).
I have took a look to this sample program: Files > Samples > Ethernet > WebServer

There is something very strange for me in loop function: When the server ends to print data to client, i see a delay:

```
// give the web browser time to receive the data
delay(1);
// close the connection:
client.stop();
```

What happens if it takes more than one second to send data to client ?
What happens if data is immediatly send and if i have a second client trying to connect to the server in the 1 second delay ?

Is there a way to do something clean, for example waiting data to be flushed instead of waiting 1 second ?

Thanks

Comment: It's a **millisecond**, not a second. I don't know the significance of the 1 millisecond delay, as it is it looks like it's only useful to get the output buffer started, similarly with what is done for Serial.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake but it does not change my question

Comment: sure, interestingly enough if you look at the code of `EthernetClient::stop()` then you find out that indeed it **does** wait up to *one second*, if the *client* doesn't answer to a request to close the connection, before closing the connection in an abrupt manner.